# How can I make debugger display new lines instead of '\r\n'?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, newline, breakpoints

In Visual Studio 2013 I set on breakpoint instruction to print content of string variable, but new lines which are present in this variable are being printed in output window as '\r\n', not visual representation of new line. How can I change that behavior?

Comment: if I remember correctly there should be a magnifying glass right next to the value - click on it - a new tool window should open where newlines are rendered as new lines

Comment: @Carsten yes it works really well!

Comment: I've used Visual Studio for 16+ years and never noticed that one!